# На сколько важно придерживаться бутстрап сетки при верстке?

Tags: вёрстка

Сделали макет по бутстраповской сетке, но во время верстки было принято решение увеличить ширину страницы. В итоге из-за того, что растянулась страница, посбивались отступы между блоками и иконками.

Не уверен, что понятно изложил, по этому скажу проще: Сверстанная страница должна соответствовать пиксель в пиксель нарисованному макету или этим можно пренебрегать?
Также хотелось бы узнать какие в последствии могут быть неприятности, если верстать страницу не по сетке, а "на глаз"?

Сделал скрин сверстанной страницы, приложил к макету и вот - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RP7di0urK4

За ранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Зависит от требований вашего заказчика и макета, который изначально у вас был. Обычно когда хотят pixel perfect, то предоставляют макет в трех размерах: для пк, для планшета, для телефона.

Answer (score 0):

А. Если в требовании pixel perfect, то придется вам работать по заданной верстке, ничего страшного или тяжелого в этом нет. Если таких требований нет, то постарайтесь сделать не просто максимально близкую к макету верстку, но и максимально гибкую к изменениям и все будет отлично. Все зависит в первую очередь от заказчика и вашего умения убедить, что ваш взгляд на макет самый правильный)